# How to install pdfcrop in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

How can I install `pdfcrop` in Ubuntu? I tried `sudo apt-get install pdfcrop` but I got the error message:

```
E: Unable to locate package pdfcrop
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

pdfcrop is provided by the texlive-extra-utils package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-extra-utils
```

Type `pdfcrop /path/to/pdf_document` from the terminal to run pdfcrop, and a new cropped pdf document will be created alongside the original pdf document.